# how to get copyright info of video in kotlin android studio?

Tags: kotlin, video

I am building app for client in kotlin language with android studio my client wants to upload videos in app and he can share to anybody but if video is copyright then users cant upload the videos to app

I searched everywhere but didn't found any solution.